# Getting type of SelectedShape in picture and content placeholder fails in VSTO

Tags: com, ms-office, office365, vsto, powerpoint

When running the following snippet of VSTO code I get a COM exception

```
if (param.SelectedShape.Type != MsoShapeType.msoPlaceholder) { //Stuff is happening }
```

The exception occurs when trying to read the `Type` property of `SelectedShape`.

We have been running with this code in PowerPoint (Office 365 ProPlus) for a long time, but somewhere between build 9126.2210 (works) and build 9330.2087 (doesn't work) it broke.

When looking through the release notes it doesn't seem like anything has been changed that should be related to this. What could have been changed?

Answer (score 1):

You might try to use the call in a try/catch block like here:

```
try
{
    if (param.SelectedShape.Type != MsoShapeType.msoPlaceholder)
    {
        // Stuff is happening
    }
}
catch (COMException)
{ 
    // Add logging here
}
```

This is a workaround. Of course, Microsoft should fix the problem.